# Microsoft Bot Framework working with database results

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to get my Dialog to work with my database.
If I have my dialog like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class QuestionDialog : IDialog<object>
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Start our response
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The current context</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {

        // Move to the next method
        context.Wait(StepOneAsync);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When our message is recieved we execute this delegate
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The current context</param>
    /// <param name="result">The result object</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task StepOneAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {

        // Get our activity
        var activity = await result;

        // Ask our first question
        await context.PostAsync("hi");

        // Get our answer
        context.Done(this);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine and I get my message as expected. I then changed it to this:

```
[Serializable]
public class QuestionDialog : IDialog<object>
{

    // Private properties
    private IList<QuestionGroup> _questionGroups;

    /// <summary>
    /// Start our response
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The current context</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {

        try

        {

            // Create our service
            var questionGroupService = new QuestionGroupService(new UnitOfWork<DatabaseContext>());

            // Add our question groups
            this._questionGroups = await questionGroupService.ListAllAsync();

            // Move to the next method
            context.Wait(StepOneAsync);
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When our message is recieved we execute this delegate
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The current context</param>
    /// <param name="result">The result object</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task StepOneAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {

        // Get our activity
        var activity = await result;

        // Ask our first question
        await context.PostAsync("hi");

        // Get our answer
        context.Done(this);
    }
}
```

And it doesn't go the the **StepOneAsync** method. Can anyone see anything glaringly obvious as to why this isn't working?

Comment: Is QuestionGroup marked as Serializable? If you hold references on your dialog, all of them needs to be Serializable (or you need to explicitly tell the dialog to threat them as not serializable)

Comment: QuestionGroup is not marked as serializable (it's from another project which I have no control over). How do I mark it as not serializable?

Comment: Try decorating the field with the attribute [NonSerialized]. I suspect this might lead you into another issues in the features if you need to use that questions groups across different messages, but will see

Comment: This seemed to work, but it gets nulled when I wait for a user response

Comment: Yep, that's the side effect I was refering to. You can try using the on deserialized attribute https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx to re hydrate the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your QestionGroup model is marked as Serializable.

If you cannot make it serializable and you still want to reference it during your dialog, you need to go with one of the alternatives described in the "[How can I reference non-serializable services from my C# dialogs?](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/technical-faq/#how-can-i-reference-non-serializable-services-from-my-c-dialogs)" section of the [Bot Framework Technical FAQ](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/technical-faq).

The simplest one is to use the [NonSerialized](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute in your field.

Alternatively, you can try using registering the Reflection Serialization Surrogate by adding it to the Autofac container. In your global.asax, try adding this code:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterModule(new ReflectionSurrogateModule());

builder.Update(Conversation.Container);
```

Comment: I did try to use Autofac before, but it ended up not working so I took it out. I was using https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AlarmBot to help me build my module.

Comment: Try with this sample: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers . It's easier. However; try adding just those lines that I posted in the Global.asax instead of using the NonSerialized

Comment: Another alternative, would be mapping the QuestionGroup object into an object you can control and that you can make sure it's serializable

Comment: hehe too late, already used the link I posted above and got the Autofac working.

Comment: Yeah I might do that

Comment: Glad it worked; the serialization issue is a tricky one; but once you get used to that you automatically mark everything as serializable :)

Comment: In the alarm one, his AlarmRingDialog has a service in it, how does that not cause any issues?

Comment: The AlarmService used in that dialog is registered in the autofac container using the FiberModule.Key_DoNotSerialize key at the registration time: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/AlarmBot/Models/AlarmModule.cs#L40